# R: What replaces memory.limit()?

Tags: r, windows, memory

I recently updated to the latest R for Windows after a 3 year hiatus. I see that the memory.limit() function is now obsolete [for some reason; it always worked well for me]. As of now what is the preferred method for determining the amount of RAM, on a Windows 10 machine, from within R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could invoke a invoke a system command.

```
system('wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel, DeviceLocator, Capacity, Speed')
# BankLabel  Capacity    DeviceLocator  Speed  
# None       4160749568  M0                    
# None       4227858432  M1                    
# 
# [1] 0
```

Similarly on Linux.

```
system('free -h')
#                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
# Mem:            31Gi       6.5Gi        17Gi       466Mi       6.9Gi        23Gi
# Swap:          2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

To store the values in an object, use `intern=TRUE`.

```
s <- system('free -h', intern=TRUE)
s
# [1] "               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available"
# [2] "Mem:            31Gi       5.9Gi        18Gi       332Mi       6.7Gi        24Gi"
# [3] "Swap:          2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi"
```

On Windows:

```
system('wmic MEMORYCHIP get BankLabel, DeviceLocator, Capacity, Speed', intern=TRUE)
```

Comment: The system() command prints to the screen but it doesn't return anything I can use in a program. I need a program to be able to access the total RAM.

Comment: @Argent use `intern=TRUE`, see update please.

Comment: Yes, Jay, that looks like it should work.